# Autocomplete cities similar to kayak.com from Postgresql with PHP and JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, postgresql, autocomplete

I would like to have a input where, when the user type in anything all the cities available appear to him. Something like the functionality in kayak.com

So if the user type in the letter M, all the cities starting with M will show like in the picture below.

[image]

So I have the following code that works but only for the options provided under var choices:

```
<form onsubmit="$('#hero-demo').blur();return false;" class="pure-form" style="border-top: 1px solid #eee;border-bottom:1px solid #eee;background:#fafafa;margin:30px 0;padding:20px 10px;text-align:center">
    <input id="hero-demo" autofocus type="text" name="q" placeholder="Programming languages ..." style="width:100%;max-width:600px;outline:0">
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.auto-complete.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#hero-demo').autoComplete({
            minChars: 1,
            source: function(term, suggest){
                term = term.toLowerCase();
                var choices = ['Birmingham', 'Dallas', 'Houston','New York', 'San Francisco'];
                var suggestions = [];
                for (i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
                    if (~choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) suggestions.push(choices[i]);
                suggest(suggestions);
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Then I have this PHP code to pull all my cities from my postgresql database:

```
<?php

   $db = pg_connect("$db_host $db_name $db_username $db_password");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM cities";
    $result = pg_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
        echo pg_last_error();
        exit();
    }

//This is just to print out all the cities I have in my database with their countries 
while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {  
    $city = $myrow[city];
    $country = $myrow[country];
       echo $city;
       echo $country;
   echo '<br>';
     }

?>
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I do to substitute the values in var choices for the values retrieve from my postgreqsl database with $query = "SELECT * FROM cities";?
2. How can I do to have also added the country so if there are two cities named the same in different countries or States all show up: Example: 
   If I type in Tole --> I'll see:

Toledo, Spain

Toledo, OH

Toledo, OR

Toledo, IA

Toledo, WA

Toledo, IL

Thank you so much

Here is the code from jquery.auto-complete.js:

```
(function($){
$.fn.autoComplete = function(options){
    var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.autoComplete.defaults, options);

    // public methods
    if (typeof options == 'string') {
        this.each(function(){
            var that = $(this);
            if (options == 'destroy') {
                $(window).off('resize.autocomplete', that.updateSC);
                that.off('blur.autocomplete focus.autocomplete keydown.autocomplete keyup.autocomplete');
                if (that.data('autocomplete'))
                    that.attr('autocomplete', that.data('autocomplete'));
                else
                    that.removeAttr('autocomplete');
                $(that.data('sc')).remove();
                that.removeData('sc').removeData('autocomplete');
            }
        });
        return this;
    }

    return this.each(function(){
        var that = $(this);
        // sc = 'suggestions container'
        that.sc = $('<div class="autocomplete-suggestions '+o.menuClass+'"></div>');
        that.data('sc', that.sc).data('autocomplete', that.attr('autocomplete'));
        that.attr('autocomplete', 'off');
        that.cache = {};
        that.last_val = '';

        that.updateSC = function(resize, next){
            that.sc.css({
                top: that.offset().top + that.outerHeight(),
                left: that.offset().left,
                width: that.outerWidth()
            });
            if (!resize) {
                that.sc.show();
                if (!that.sc.maxHeight) that.sc.maxHeight = parseInt(that.sc.css('max-height'));
                if (!that.sc.suggestionHeight) that.sc.suggestionHeight = $('.autocomplete-suggestion', that.sc).first().outerHeight();
                if (that.sc.suggestionHeight)
                    if (!next) that.sc.scrollTop(0);
                    else {
                        var scrTop = that.sc.scrollTop(), selTop = next.offset().top - that.sc.offset().top;
                        if (selTop + that.sc.suggestionHeight - that.sc.maxHeight > 0)
                            that.sc.scrollTop(selTop + that.sc.suggestionHeight + scrTop - that.sc.maxHeight);
                        else if (selTop < 0)
                            that.sc.scrollTop(selTop + scrTop);
                    }
            }
        }
        $(window).on('resize.autocomplete', that.updateSC);

        that.sc.appendTo('body');

        that.sc.on('mouseleave', '.autocomplete-suggestion', function (){
            $('.autocomplete-suggestion.selected').removeClass('selected');
        });

        that.sc.on('mouseenter', '.autocomplete-suggestion', function (){
            $('.autocomplete-suggestion.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });

        that.sc.on('mousedown click', '.autocomplete-suggestion', function (e){
            var item = $(this), v = item.data('val');
            if (v || item.hasClass('autocomplete-suggestion')) { // else outside click
                that.val(v);
                o.onSelect(e, v, item);
                that.sc.hide();
            }
            return false;
        });

        that.on('blur.autocomplete', function(){
            try { over_sb = $('.autocomplete-suggestions:hover').length; } catch(e){ over_sb = 0; } // IE7 fix :hover
            if (!over_sb) {
                that.last_val = that.val();
                that.sc.hide();
                setTimeout(function(){ that.sc.hide(); }, 350); // hide suggestions on fast input
            } else if (!that.is(':focus')) setTimeout(function(){ that.focus(); }, 20);
        });

        if (!o.minChars) that.on('focus.autocomplete', function(){ that.last_val = '\n'; that.trigger('keyup.autocomplete'); });

        function suggest(data){
            var val = that.val();
            that.cache[val] = data;
            if (data.length && val.length >= o.minChars) {
                var s = '';
                for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) s += o.renderItem(data[i], val);
                that.sc.html(s);
                that.updateSC(0);
            }
            else
                that.sc.hide();
        }

        that.on('keydown.autocomplete', function(e){
            // down (40), up (38)
            if ((e.which == 40 || e.which == 38) && that.sc.html()) {
                var next, sel = $('.autocomplete-suggestion.selected', that.sc);
                if (!sel.length) {
                    next = (e.which == 40) ? $('.autocomplete-suggestion', that.sc).first() : $('.autocomplete-suggestion', that.sc).last();
                    that.val(next.addClass('selected').data('val'));
                } else {
                    next = (e.which == 40) ? sel.next('.autocomplete-suggestion') : sel.prev('.autocomplete-suggestion');
                    if (next.length) { sel.removeClass('selected'); that.val(next.addClass('selected').data('val')); }
                    else { sel.removeClass('selected'); that.val(that.last_val); next = 0; }
                }
                that.updateSC(0, next);
                return false;
            }
            // esc
            else if (e.which == 27) that.val(that.last_val).sc.hide();
            // enter or tab
            else if (e.which == 13 || e.which == 9) {
                var sel = $('.autocomplete-suggestion.selected', that.sc);
                if (sel.length && that.sc.is(':visible')) { o.onSelect(e, sel.data('val'), sel); setTimeout(function(){ that.sc.hide(); }, 20); }
            }
        });

        that.on('keyup.autocomplete', function(e){
            if (!~$.inArray(e.which, [13, 27, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40])) {
                var val = that.val();
                if (val.length >= o.minChars) {
                    if (val != that.last_val) {
                        that.last_val = val;
                        clearTimeout(that.timer);
                        if (o.cache) {
                            if (val in that.cache) { suggest(that.cache[val]); return; }
                            // no requests if previous suggestions were empty
                            for (var i=1; i<val.length-o.minChars; i++) {
                                var part = val.slice(0, val.length-i);
                                if (part in that.cache && !that.cache[part].length) { suggest([]); return; }
                            }
                        }
                        that.timer = setTimeout(function(){ o.source(val, suggest) }, o.delay);
                    }
                } else {
                    that.last_val = val;
                    that.sc.hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

$.fn.autoComplete.defaults = {
    source: 0,
    minChars: 3,
    delay: 150,
    cache: 1,
    menuClass: '',
    renderItem: function (item, search){
        // escape special characters
        search = search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
        var re = new RegExp("(" + search.split(' ').join('|') + ")", "gi");
        return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-val="' + item + '">' + item.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>") + '</div>';
    },
    onSelect: function(e, term, item){}
};
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like this plugin called [awesomeplete.](https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/) Light, easy to use. It is very flexible with how you attach the options.